# Enabling NIC under Ubuntu 15.04 on Dell Optiplex 9020

Tags: networking, dell, intel, wakeonlan, nic

I have a brand-new Dell Optiplex 9020 with an i7-4790 and 32 GB RAM. The motherboard has an Intel Q87 chipset and an Intel I217-LM Gigabit Ethernet chip.

The Ethernet works fine under Windows 7. It also works when I live-boot Knoppix 7.4.2. But when I install Ubuntu 15.04 from DVD (downloaded from Canonical) the install went OK but I could not get the Ethernet to work. Using "lspci" shows that Linux recognizes the device.

If I go into Settings and say to use DHCP for IPv4 (which is what my workplace wants), the icon in the upper right corner of the screen keeps pulsating as if it is trying to connect, and eventually gives up. If I set the IP address, netmask, gateway, and DNS to the specific values which DHCP returns to Windows 7, then ipconfig shows all the right values, but trying to do anything I still get the message that the network is unreachable.

I tried installing the e1000e driver downloaded from Intel and the installation did not give any error messages, but the driver does not appear in the correct directory. I do the insmod and again no error message, but still the NIC does not work. The documentation for the Intel driver says it is for kernel 2.4 and 2.6, and Ubuntu is at kernel 3.19, so I wonder if the extra driver is even necessary.

According to Dell and Canonical, the Optiplex 9020 is compatible with Ubuntu 12.04, so I downloaded that from Canonical and have the same problem. Same with Ubuntu 14.04 and the latest Fedora.

So, what I am looking for is a Linux distro I can install that does work on this hardware (Knoppix does this, but I was hoping for a more widely-used distro). Or I would like a way to get Ubuntu to work; and if Ubuntu can be patched, the best way to do that. Without a working network I cannot install updates, but since the system is bootable in Windows I can download files to a separate partition on the boot drive (or to USB) and access those after installation.

I have access to other Linux and Windows machines as needed. I can also probably find an Ethernet card I can plug into one of the expansion slots and use that temporarily. Thanks in advance for any help or insight you can give.

Comment: Still looking for a solution. I am temporarily using a USB-to-Ethernet converter, which works fine, but I want to get the native port working.

Comment: Still looking for an answer! I downloaded the e1000e driver from Intel, which now says that it works on 3.x kernels. After several tries ti started working, and continued to work after several reboots. So I thought I had the problem solved. But a few days ago it stopped working again. Can anyone confirm that the got this Ethernet chip to work on Ubunut 15.04?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Windows' Intel network adapter Power Management setting "**Wake on Magic Packet from power off state**" seems to cause this issue. Disabling it seems to allow Ubuntu to access the network, following a restart from Microsoft Windows.

DISABLING SETTING "WAKE ON MAGIC PACKET FROM POWER OFF STATE"

- Start Microsoft Windows
- Open Device Manager

  - Start > Control Panel
  - System and Security
  - Under System, select Device Manager
  - Note: Administrator permission required--if you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
- In Device Manager, expand Network Adapters, right-click the adapter, then select Properties
- In Properties window, select tab "Power Management"
- **Clear checkbox "Wake on Magic Packet from power off state"**
- Select button "OK" to save and exit

Note: we first installed the latest drivers via the Intel Download Center: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/60019/Intel-Ethernet-Connection-I217-LM . Namely, as of this writing: Network Adapter Driver for Windows 7*, Version: 20.4.1 (Latest), Date: 10/2/2015 . You may or may not need to do this, to clear the setting listed above.

Our setup: Dell Optiplex 9020 MT (i7), Intel i217-LM network card, dual boot of Microsoft Windows 7 and Ubuntu 15.04 (both 64-bit).